# Import error: cannot import name 'label_cython'

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, caffe, intel, importerror, pycaffe

I am a new user for Ubuntu16.04 as well as caffe.

Few days ago I was working with Intel Movidius with the ncappzoo thingy and it worked. Afterward I tried to download the toolkit and API to play with. As I was verifying the installation of the toolkit, I found that the function importing `caffe` can no longer work. It keeps giving me this error.

I tried googling but find no solution. The `$PYTHONPATH` was check and verified. I also reinstalled the `scikit-image`.

Here's the block of gibberish  thingy it bounced back to me :

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "/workspace/SDK/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>  
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer  
  File "/workspace/SDK/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 15, in <module>  
    import caffe.io  
  File "/workspace/SDK/caffe/python/caffe/io.py", line 4, in <module>  
    from skimage.transform import resize  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/transform/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>  
    from .hough_transform import (hough_line, hough_line_peaks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/transform/hough_transform.py", line 3, in <module>  
    from .. import measure  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/measure/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>  
    from ._regionprops import regionprops, perimeter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/measure/_regionprops.py", line 7, in <module>  
    from ._label import label  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/measure/_label.py", line 1, in <module>   
    from ._ccomp import label_cython as clabel  
ImportError: cannot import name 'label_cython'
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: So what source exactly did you use, and how did you run it, to produce those error messages?  Include steps to reproduce so this is a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

We are able to make use of all the apps/networks available from ncappzoo without any issues.

```
Our configuration is as follows:
    movidius@osboxes:~$ python --version
    Python 2.7.12
    movidius@osboxes:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
    :/opt/movidius/caffe/python
    movidius@osboxes:~$ lscpu | grep "Model name"
    Model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    movidius@osboxes:~$ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial
```

Assuming that you have downloaded the ncsdk and then installed it. If not,

First we need to install 'ncsdk' which enable rapid prototyping, validation, and deployment of deep neural networks

please follow the links mentioned below to install ncsdk 
(It includes software tools, API and examples)

1. https://developer.movidius.com/start
2. https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/install.html

   once the ncsdk installation is suceessfull, then you can make use of all the apps/networks available in ncappzoo.